# Android ConnectionService with Twilio

Tags: android, react-native, twilio, voip

I'm working on an app that allow users communicate between through Twilio. This is working using FCM notifications where when the call is answered It's possible to speak and hear normally.

Due to the fact that I have to build a UI dial to manage the controls of the calling, I was thinking about use [ConnectionService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telecom/ConnectionService.html) where the doc says that it support VOIP; and I would be dismissed of build the UI.

Now I'm stuck; I don't know how to merge those two tools.

When I start a calling (Twilio) I also call the TelecomManager which tries to open the Android UI Phone, see the code bellow:

```
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("tel", params.getString("To"), null);
Bundle callInfoBundle = new Bundle();
callInfoBundle.putString("to", params.getString("To"));
Bundle callInfo = new Bundle();
callInfo.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_OUTGOING_CALL_EXTRAS,callInfoBundle);
callInfo.putParcelable(TelecomManager.EXTRA_PHONE_ACCOUNT_HANDLE, handle);
tm.placeCall(uri, callInfo);
tm.showInCallScreen(true);
Log.d(TAG,"Outgoing call successful");
```

At this point, I can see for a short period the Android UI Phone, with the **params** and on top of it says **"Disconected"**.

I also read that I should be using SIP, only that way the Android will work, but I know nothing more.

I'm new on this and I'm not sure if I'm on the right path, maybe I should keep building my own UI dial like [this suggestion](http://belka.us/en/callkit-android-react-native/); but first I would like to know if it's worth keep on this track of use **ConnectionService**.

- https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/157363/is-there-an-android-equivalent-to-ioss-callkit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The Android Voice SDK team have been looking into using `ConnectionService`, but we don't have an example of it right now. There is an [ongoing discussion on GitHub](https://github.com/twilio/voice-quickstart-android/issues/95) that you might get some insight from, but that's all I have for you right now.

Comment: I'm already in that discussion but I decided to move on creating an specific screen on native code which worked for now. Anyway thank you again for your time.

Comment: @Pablo You said you decided to move on to a different approach. Could you please elaborate in a separate answer possibly. It would be helpful to other users like me facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

we're doing Cordova + CallKit + Twilio. Currently struggling with the Android bit.

This is a plugin which uses iOS Callkit and Android(Connection Service)
https://github.com/mattkhaw/cordova-plugin-callkit

which is based on another which has more documentation
https://github.com/WebsiteBeaver/CordovaCall

the main code is in the onAnswer nested method.
Our first big issue is in ConnectioNService and the MainActivity respond to the VOIP push at same time so when user presses onAnswer and we switch to the TwilioVideoActivity the call might not be connected. I had to put in a delay.

Also there should be only one instance of the TwilioVideoActivity. launchMode:singleInstance.

One gotcha is the VOIP screen on older Android is full screen and its own activity called  InCallActivity but on Android 10 when you answer a call it just a small drop down which appears and has two DECLINE/ANSWER buttons.

A useful adb command which will show you the TASK and Activities stacks and show you the InCallActivity and where your activity is hidden is :

```
/Users/gbxc/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell dumpsys activity activities | sed -En -e '/Stack #/p' -e '/Running activities/,/Run #0/p'
```